# Sum of Even and Odd Integers in an Interval

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

> Let $f(x) = x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} + ... + x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - ax + b$. Which value for the pair $(a,b)$ will insure that the x-axis will be tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ at $x=1$.

Okay. First of all, I feel obliged to mention that I am rather miserable at counting. For instance, I still have trouble with $n-0=n$ being the number of integers in $[0,n)$ or $[0,n]$. After some effort, I was able to show that the condition $f(1) = 0$ implies $1 -a + b = 0$. Now I am trying to draw the imnplications of the implication $f'(1) = 0$.  Since $f(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{2n} (-1)^k x^k -ax + b$, $f'(x) = \sum_{k=3}^{2n} (-1)^k k x^{k-1} - a$. Hence 
$$0=f'(1) = \sum_{k=3}^{2n} (-1)^k k - a = \sum_{k \in \{3,...,2n\}, \mbox{ even }} k - \sum_{k \in \{3,...,2n\}, \mbox{ odd }} k - a$$

At this point I am not sure what to do. There has got to be a faster way to see all of this, especially because this is a question on a timed test (it has to be done within a minute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\in\{4,6,8,\dots, 2n\}} k = \sum_{i=2}^n 2i = 2\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n i -2 = 2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-2 = n(n+1)-2 = n^2+n-2$$

You can do something similar for the sum over the odd integers:

$$\sum_{k\in\{3,5,7,9,\dots, 2n-1\}}k = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(2i+1) =\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}1 = 2\frac{(n-1)n}{2} + n-1 = n^2-n+n-1=n^2-1$$

Comment: Why does your index $k$ start at $2$?

Comment: @user193319 Oh, I didn't see you start at 3. Well, just subtract $2$ from the result :)